# How to adjust the search in file behavior in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, search

Currently, when I using vim searching "/searchforsth" with "n" to search for words. After navigating through the words on this page, the next word that is not on the current page will appear at the bottom. But I am used to the behavior that this word will display on top or middle of this page, just like pressing "zt" or "zz". So I can see the following code of this searched pattern. Is there a way to define this behavior by myself? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by advising `evil-ex-search` as follows:

```
  (advice-add 'evil-ex-search :after #'recenter)
```